# Android studio doesnt recognise EncryptedSharedPreferences import

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, androidx

So I'm trying to create the Encrypted Shared prefs as shown in the dev android side  : https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences#inherited-methods
And android studio doesn't seem to recognize it all all.
My min skd is 23 is that reason form what I understand so far androidx doesnt require the newest android version?

Tried clean rebuild build etc.
Tried migrating to androidx from Android studio menu ( getting the message of no usages found in project but I do have a few imports for androidx as I understood after checking it out)

```
import androidx.security.crypto.EncryptedSharedPreferences;


 String masterKeyAlias = MasterKeys.getOrCreate(MasterKeys.AES256_GCM_SPEC);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = EncryptedSharedPreferences.create(
                "secret_shared_prefs",
                masterKeyAlias,
                context,
                EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefKeyEncryptionScheme.AES256_SIV,
                EncryptedSharedPreferences.PrefValueEncryptionScheme.AES256_GCM
        );

//doesnt recognise MasterKeys nor EncryptedSharedPreferences classes
```

Answer (score 5):

As per the [`androidx.security` Declaring dependencies documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/security#declaring_dependencies), you need to add the dependency on the library:

```
dependencies {
    def security_version = "1.0.0-alpha02"
    implementation "androidx.security:security-crypto:$security_version"
}
```

Comment: minSdkVersion cannot be smaller than version 23

Comment: @Praveen - that is indeed the minSdkVersion for security. Feel free to star [the existing issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132325342) for lowering the minSdkVersion

Comment: @ianhanniballake I know the library is still in alpha version. How safe is it to use it in production? I want to use `EncryptedSharedPreferences` to store the tokens.

Comment: @sam33r - regarding 'alpha' for AndroidX libraries, the alpha is about API stability (it may change in future alphas when you choose to upgrade) and *not* about runtime stability. For reference, Google apps use the alpha versions of all AndroidX libraries.

Comment: What do you mean by API stability? Does that mean the public interface could change from one version to the other?

Comment: @Blackbelt - yes, that's precisely what API stability means

Comment: @ianhanniballake my app's minSdkVersion is `21`. I am planning to write a wrapper class that is backed by `EncryptedSharedPreferences` for api >=23 and my custom solution for api below 23. I am getting `Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 21 cannot be smaller than version 23 declared in library [androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0-alpha02]` message. Is it good idea to do force usage using tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.security" ?

Comment: I am scared by `use tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.security" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)` message.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to build.gradle file

```
api 'androidx.security:security-crypto:1.0.0'
```